# How to keep all log files?

Tags: osx, logs, backup

I just lost important log file. Time Machine etc is not in use in that Mac.

I would like to setup in my Mac (El Capitan) some unix thingie, which keeps all log files.

Logs rotate, right? So if i just copy log files every x days, i might lost some log entries because that log was rotated already.

Is there any unix tool which saves all logs?

Comment: I don't know about a specific tool to store all logs, but reading this http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-rotate-log-files/ I think you could disable the log rotation, copy log files every x days, and remove the local copy manually. Or better, create a cron job that periodically do it. Maybee rsync can also be usefull for your scope.

Comment: I'm not an OSX expert, so: why is Time Machine not the obvious answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use many backup methods including mysql backups of log files.

Here is a good place to start for a simple method. http://simplelinuxbkup.sourceforge.net/